# asp.net gridview command field and custom edit

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a gridview that is serviced by a sqldatasource and I was just wondering how is it possible to have the Edit button do something other than put the gridview row in edit mode.

```
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" ShowEditButton="true" ButtonType="Button" />
```

What I want to do is have a custom edit page/control that is loaded when you click Edit.
As opposed to just put the row in edit mode and turn the fields into editable textboxes.

Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options that come to my mind:

**Use EditTemplates for your GridView fields**
This will let you customize the look / content of each of the fields when they go into edit mode.

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ...>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <!-- child controls -->
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <!-- child controls -->
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

**Handle the RowEditing event**
You can handle the [`RowEditing` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting.aspx) to do whatever manipulation on the Gridview that you want in repsonse to a "Edit" button in the row being clicked.

Comment: Was trying out the RowEditing method but that still puts the row into edit mode. How can I make it not do that?

Comment: You can use the "Cancel" property of the GridViewEditEventArgs object that gets passwed to the RowEditing event.  Setting that to "true" will cancel the edit operation.  But I think what you really want is to have a custom control / control structure inside EditItemTemplate of each of your fields @sd_dracula.

Comment: Yeah that could work but since I need to get onto another page I can just do a Response.Redirect() and that will go to the new page without getting to put the row in edit mode.